# C Parent/Child exit variable

Tags: c, variables, parent-child

I am working on a program and learning about parent/child processes. 
Currently my childprocess does

```
exit(variable);
```

in my main() I have:

```
signal(SIGCHLD, chldHandler);
```

outside my main() I have:

```
void chldHandler(int sig) {

}
```

How do I access the variable from my chldHandler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `wait()` inside your signal handler, passing in a non-NULL pointer to get the status.

```
int status;
wait(&status);
```

To decode the status, check to see that it exited normally, then use the `WEXITSTATUS()` macro:

```
if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
    int variable = WEXITSTATUS(status);
    /*...*/
}
```